# MDbootstrap specify where DataTable search component renders

Tags: bootstrap-4, material-design, frontend, mdbootstrap

In using MDbootstrap's DataTables - which provides great functionality by the way - I would like to specify where the search bar loads.

It injects itself above my table, which is throwing off my page like so:

[image]

Is there a way that I can specify where this div loads with an html `id=""`? I'd like it up by my new button.